# Data on table not showing up JavaFX, lets me select cells just no text there

Tags: java, javafx

class

```
public class Product {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private double price;
    private int year;
    private int kilom;

    public Product(){
        this.model ="";
        this.price=0;
        this.kilom = 0;
        this.make= "";
        this.year = 0;
    }

    public Product(String make,String model, double price,int year, int kilom){
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
        this.year = year;
        this.kilom = kilom;

    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getKilom() {
        return kilom;
    }

    public void setKilom(int kilom) {
        this.kilom = kilom;
    }

}
```

main class

```
public class CarInventory2 extends Application {
    Stage window;
    TableView<Product> table;
    TextField makeInput, modelInput, priceInput, yearInput, kiloInput;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);

    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Car Ineventory System");
        //make column
         TableColumn<Product,String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Make");
        nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Make"));


        //model column
        TableColumn<Product,String> modelColumn = new TableColumn<>("Model");
        nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Model"));


        //price column
        TableColumn<Product,Double> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
       nameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Price"));

        //year column
        TableColumn<Product,Integer> yearColumn = new TableColumn<>("Year");
        nameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Year"));



        //mileage column
        TableColumn<Product,Integer> kilomColumn = new TableColumn<>("Kilo");
       nameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
       nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Kilo"));



       //make input
       makeInput = new TextField();
       makeInput.setPromptText("make");
       makeInput.setMinWidth(100);




       modelInput= new TextField();
       modelInput.setPromptText("model");
       modelInput.setMinWidth(100);


       priceInput = new TextField();
       priceInput.setPromptText("price");
       priceInput.setMinWidth(100);


       yearInput = new TextField();
       yearInput.setPromptText("year");
       yearInput.setMinWidth(100);


       kiloInput = new TextField();
       kiloInput.setPromptText("KM");
       kiloInput.setMinWidth(100);

       //Button

       Button addButton = new Button("Add");
       addButton.setOnAction(e-> addButtonClicked());
       Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
      // deleteButton.setOnAction(e-> deleteButtonClicked());

       HBox hBox = new HBox();
       hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
       hBox.setSpacing(10);
       hBox.getChildren().addAll(makeInput,modelInput,priceInput,
               yearInput,kiloInput,addButton,deleteButton);



        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getProduct());
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, modelColumn, priceColumn, 
                yearColumn, kilomColumn);




        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(table,hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }

    public ObservableList<Product> getProduct(){
        ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        products.add(new Product("Honda","Accord",7000,2011,86000));
        products.add(new Product("Honda","Civic",4000,2007,146000));
        products.add(new Product("Honda","Prelude",1000,2000,186000));
        products.add(new Product("Honda","type R",40000,2018,0));
        return products;
    }
    public void addButtonClicked(){
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setMake(makeInput.getText());
        product.setModel(modelInput.getText());
        product.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(priceInput.getText()));
        product.setYear(Integer.parseInt(yearInput.getText()));
        product.setKilom(Integer.parseInt(kiloInput.getText()));
        table.getItems().add(product);
        makeInput.clear();
        modelInput.clear();
        priceInput.clear();
        yearInput.clear();
        kiloInput.clear();
    }
}
```

please someone help me with this... been pulling my hair out for hours, all my setters and getters are public and it lets me click the cells, when I use my add method it also lets me click the new cell underneath so its just something with the text not showing up in the cells, donno what else it could be at this point

Comment: 2 Errors here 1) Copy&paste error: You always set the properties of the `nameColumn` 2) The last assignments are the ones where you're using the wrong parameter for `PropertyValueFactory`: it should be `"kilom"` not `"Kilo"`.

Comment: Hey! I figured it out last night right before I went to bed and yup this was the exact problem , good eye lool took me forever